# Create a Robot.txt file on Wordpress in PHP Script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am a newbie in Wordpress Plugin Development and I had a question that I needed answered.
Is it possible to generate Files like Robot.txt through a plugin if it is how can it be done? 
I have tried a number of solutions like `file_put_contents` but it doesn't seem to be working because there might be permission issues I think.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
if (! defined('ABSPATH')){
die;
}

$rfile='../../../robot.txt';
$rtext="User-Agent: *
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-admin/";
file_put_contents($rfile, $rtext);
```

Here is the code i am using as of now.

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `robots_txt` hook in WordPress to add to the `robots.txt` file.

For example:

```
function AddToRobotsTxt($robotstext, $public) {
    $robotsrules = "User-agent: SomeBot
                    Allow: /";
    return $robotstext . $robotsrules;
}
add_filter('robots_txt', 'AddToRobotsTxt', 10, 2);
```

You can also completely replace the `robots.txt` file with your own dynamically using this hook. You would do something like this in your `functions.php` file:

```
function ReplaceRobotsTxt($robotstext, $public) {
    $robotstext = "User-agent: SomeBot
                   Allow: /";
    return $robotstext;
}
add_filter('robots_txt', 'ReplaceRobotsTxt', 10, 2);
```

Regarding the last two arguments in the `add_filter` function, the 10 is the `$priority` argument which defines when your function will run with respect to other functions. The 2 is the `$accepted_args` parameter which tells WP how many parameters the function you want to add will take.

For more info on the `robots_txt` hook, [check out this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/robots_txt/).

Comment: Have tried the following but it doesn't,t work when plugin created is activated. Do I have to change some settings in http.conf file. Clarification would be appreciated.